# $K$ and $gKg^{-1}$ have the same cardinality

Tags: group-theory

How do I show that $K$ and $gKg^{-1}$ have the same cardinality for some $K$ that is a subset of $G$? I thought I might use Lagrange's theorem, but it's obvious that cosets have the same cardinality, but then I don't know how to include the second term.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Consider the map $$k \mapsto gkg^{-1}$$

Can you show that it is both $1-1$ and onto?

Comment: It's easily onto, right? The only way for it to be zero is if k is zero. So to show that it is $1-1$ we just need to show the range is the entirety of the codomain... So then for every $gkg^{-1}$ there is certainly a k? I mean, for obvious reasons?

Comment: @Tony Yes, it's onto simply by the definition of the symbol $gKg^{-1}$. To show it's one-to-one, suppose that $gkg^{-1} = glg^{-1}$ and see how $k$ and $l$ are related.

Comment: Why would I suppose it equals one?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For every $g$ and $h$ in the group $G$, the maps $G\to G$, $k\mapsto gk$ and $G\to G$, $k\mapsto kh$ are both one-to-one and onto. This can be seen by checking the two conditions or by exhibiting inverses.

Comment: I know that... I suppose I should just ignore the idea of cosets. 
Thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous i guess you could prove that left and right cosets are of the same size which is the same size as $K$